# Run script from main script in spyder-project

Tags: python, spyder

I have a spyder-project with two scripts: "mainScript.py" and "subScript.py". How can I run "subScript.py" from "mainScript.py" to do some thing with current workspace-variables? What kind of command i must to use?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `subScript.py` from within the `mainScript.py` like you would call another file from a library. But it would definitely be easier if the contents of `subScript.py' is within some function.

e.g. if your setup is:

```
Project File
- mainScript.py
- subScript.py
```

and `subScript.py` is some file like:

```
#imports    
def some_function(some_variable):
        #does something here
```

then in your `mainScript.py` you should just be able to import and use it. e.g.:

```
from sub import some_function
def main():
    variable = 'some value'
    some_function(variable) #should call the function using your variable
    #rest of your code

main()
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not an option for me. I have too many variables in my workspace that i want to change. And after script evaluating i want to create many variables too. That is why function, that you offer will look to heavy.